# PouchDB/CouchDB Replication Fails with Method Not Allowed

Tags: javascript, couchdb, cors, pouchdb

Trying to get www.server1.com to communicate to a CouchDB installed on www.server2.com using PouchDB. When trying to replicate the data, I get the following error:

```
error: true
message: "Database encountered an unknown error"
name: "unknown_error"
status: 405
statusText: "Method Not Allowed"
```

From the server:

```
$ curl -X GET http://admin:secret@127.0.0.1:5984/_config/cors
{"credentials":"false","origins":"*","methods":"GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS",
"headers":"accept,authorization,content-type,origin,X-Couch-Id,X-Couch-Rev"}
```

And in the JavaScript:

```
var localDB, remoteDB, allSynced = null; 

function initializePouch(){
  localDB = new PouchDB('databaseone');
  remoteDB = new PouchDB('http://admin:secret@<remote ip>:5984/databaseone');

  localDB.info().then(function (info) {
    console.log('Get DB info', info);
  });

  retryReplication();
}

function retryReplication() {
  localDB.sync(remoteDB, {live: true}).on('change', function (change) {
    console.log('Replication done.');
  }).on('error', function (err) {
    console.log('error while replicating');
    console.log(err);
    if( !allSynced ) {
      setTimeout(retryReplication, 30000);
    }
  });
}
initializePouch();
```

Here is the content of the console:

```
start.html:229 Get DB info Object {doc_count: 0, update_seq: 0, db_name: "database",
auto_compaction: false}
```

I tried with and without the admin:secret, but failed each time.
Apache CouchDB 1.6.1

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a CORS error. If I had to guess, I'd say you need to set `credentials` to `true` on your server. If you're ever unsure, just run the `add-cors-to-couchdb` script and try after that.

Comment: I did try to run add-cors-to-couchdb and it does not seem to do anything. Here's my current local.ini config (I confirmed with couchdb -c that it's the last one in the list).

   "httpd":{
      "enable_cors":"true",
   },
   "cors":{
      "credentials":"true",
      "headers":"accept,authorization,content-type,origin,X-Couch-Id,X-Couch-Rev",
      "methods":"GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS,HEAD"
   },

Comment: From sshing on the box, I can get request to work. And they require authentification.
From my local I try this and I can't get to the box.
curl -X GET http://admin:secret@<ip address>:5984/_config/cors

Comment: Nevermind, it was a damn issue with the ports opened on the server. Your cors idea was still good and must have worked if I had the ports opened :) Thanks!